# How to hover on linting or other icons in editor using Vim?

Tags: vimrc, vscode

So I use VsCode with Vim emulation. I use linting and helpers when I code.

I would like to know how I can hover over linting with Vim so those help messages appear or just how to work with hovering with Vim overall?

Here some VsCode examples of what I mean:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Comment: Can you please [edit] and clarify what you aim to do and what your setup is (VsCode + a Vim plugin, or just Vim and you're mentioning VsCode as an example? It's hard to tell.)? It _sounds_ like you want to trigger the hover behavior of VsCode (which you might normally achieve with the mouse) via Vim mechanisms. If that's the case, that's probably off-topic (cf. [help/on-topic]), because (1) Vim has no notion of "hovering" and (2) it really is about VsCode behavior.

Comment: right, I am in vscode shorcuts. Sorry. Its alt + .